# Import the Nintex workflow (.nwf) using Nintex dll

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, web-services, nintex

I want to import the Nintex workflow, which has been exported as (.nwf) programmatically.

As referred from the link, http://johanolivier.blogspot.in/2011/03/import-and-publish-nintex-workflows.html it is possible using web service.

I have tried that and it is working fine. But i want to do it using `Nintex.WorkFlow.dll`.

So can anyone help me on this?